# Integration question and non-riemann integrable

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, riemann-integration

Let $f(x)= x$ if $x$ is irrational and $0$ if $x$ is rational.

Then $f$ is not integrable because
for any partition $P$ of $[0,1]$, the lower sum $L(f,P)=0$, because every sub interval of $P$ contains rationals. Further note that $U(f,P)\geq \int^{1}_{0}x dx = \frac{1}{2}$. Hence for $\epsilon= \frac{1}{2}$, for any partition $P$ of $[a,b]$, we have $U(f,P)-L(f,P)\geq \frac{1}{2}$. Hence $f$ is not integrable.
Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: I assume you mean integrable over $[a,b]$? Anyway, your reasoning seems sound to me.

Comment: I meant [0,1], to be clear.

Comment: It does not matter for this proof, only that you are considering a compact interval. Anyway, as I said before, your proof is correct.